# what is the best way to give response to client that all entities are successfully stored on datastore using objectify

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I am storing multiple entities of same kind on datastore on single hit from the client.
here is the model class:

```
@Entity
public class Student {
        @Id
        Long id;
        @Index
        String status;
        String time;
        @Ignore
        String log;
        @Ignore
        List<Student> StudentList;
}
```

At my Student endpoint I am storing student list using below code:

```
ofy().save().entities(student.getStudentList()).now();
```

I have to store thousands of students on single request from client. For that I have an excel sheet which has more than 50000 students. At client side, I read the excel sheet and make a request to store all the student on the datastore. Till now I successfully stored 25 student from excel sheet which has 25 students only.

Questions:
1) Is it the correct way to store large number of same kind of entities on single hit from the client

2)how objectify do that at backend side in terms of read write operations?

3)how can I give response to the client that all entities are successfully stored on datastore or not? Currently I am returning the stored entities like `ofy().load().entities(studentList);`,
but I dont wanted to give the stored entities in  response because of large number of entities.

Comment: Did you get the answer?

Comment: not yet. but i have something in my mind like calculating checksum(client_checksum) of the data at client side then send the checksum to server while making request to sever then i will again calculate the checksum(server_checksum) of inserted data and will match both the checksum. If both checksum are equal then it means all entities coming from client side has been successfully store on datastore. there might be a need of sorting data before calculating checksum at client and server side. It just a way that I am thinking , will post answer when implemented successfully.

Answer (score 0):

1- as far as my understanding, yes this is the correct way of storing large number of same kind of entities. There may be some other better way also. please let me know if anyone find the better way.

2- during insert, write operations depends on indexing, storing to datastore. since there is one indexed field therefore 2 write operations will be there for storing single entity. 1 for indexing and 1 for storing that entity on datastore.

3- **Client side** :I did the same thing as I mentioned in my comment, first read all the student data from the excel sheet, each student have roll number also. while reading the data from the excel, make a list of roll numbers. transform the list into a specific order e.g. ascending or descending order. concatenate the roll number and make a long length single string. calculate the hash of that string using any hashing algorithm and send this hash to server in query parameter(or path parameter or other way) along with students data.

**server side**: insert the student data, load the inserted entities using `ofy().load().entities(studenList);`

form a list of roll number from loaded student entities. transform the list into same order you have done at client side i.e. ascending or descending. 
concatenate the roll number and make a long length single string. calculate the hash of that string using same hashing algorithm.
now compare this hash with hash coming from the client in query parameter. If both hash are equal then all the student data coming from the client has been successfully stored on datastore.
you can also send this server side hash to client so the client also can verify.

Answer (score 0):

My method is that you can use the result of the save operation as given below:

```
Map<Key<Student>, Student> = ofy().save().entities(student.getStudentList()).now();
```

You can traverse and get all keys inside the map. Then you can return the all generated ids from keys in the list in an API call. Also, objectify throws a runtime exception if some error occurs.